# ¿No se conecta a la base de datos en el host o algo está mal?

Tags: php, mysqli, host

bueno, miren. El script en modo local me funciona, pero cuando lo subo a cualquier servidor(en este caso uno llamado "awardspace" no me funciona pero tampoco da error, o sea, todo está normal, no hay errores. Cuando le doy a registrar en la página me aparece que sí me registré, pero cuando entro a phpmyadmin no aparece la cuenta y cuando intento iniciar sesión en mi sitio me dice que el usuario no existe. No sé a qué se deba esto, ya he revisado que los datos del connect estén correctos varias veces.
Miren una captura de los datos:
https://prnt.sc/pxyuxv
Gracias.

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("fdb16.awardspace.net", "3224335_debater", "****************", "3224335_debater");

if(isset($_POST['register'])){
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];
if($password === $password2){
$sql2 = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
 $q = mysqli_query($db, $sql2);
if( mysqli_num_rows($q) == 0){
$password = md5($password);
$sql = ("INSERT INTO users VALUES('','$username','$email','$password', '','','','images/default.png','','','','')");
mysqli_query($db, $sql);
mysqli_close($db);
echo '<script language="javascript">
document.getElementById("1").style.display = "block";
</script>'; 
}else{
echo '<script language="javascript">
document.getElementById("2").style.display = "block";
</script>'; }
 }else{
 echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("3").style.display = "block";

 </script>'; 
 }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. El código compartido es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques y no debería usarse en entornos de producción.

Answer (score 1):

Como no has mencionado el error.
Haga una prueba de conexion apartado.
Recuerda que se no esté en un servidor local debes informar el ip del servidor.

Prueba de conexion:

```
<?php
$dbname ="mi_base_de_datos";
$usuario = "mi_usuario";
$password = "mi_contraseña";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","","$dbname");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Change database to "mi_base_de_datos"
mysqli_select_db($con,"mi_base_de_datos");
echo 'conexion exitosa';
?>
```

Suludos

Comment: conexion exitosa